# How to get all actuator endpoints programatically using spring boot 2?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

In spring boot 1.x it was possible to resolve all actuator endpoints programatically. I have a bean that exposes all actuator endpoints paths

```
@Component
public class MyProjectActuatorEndpoints {

    @Autowired
    private MvcEndpoints endpoints;

    public String[] getActuatorEndpointPaths() {
        return endpoints.getEndpoints().stream()
            .map(MvcEndpoint::getPath)
            .map(path -> path + "/**")
            .toArray(String[]::new);
    }
}
```

Unfortunately in spring boot actuator 2.0.5.RELEASE there is no such class MvcEndpoints. Is there any replacement for this class in the new spring version?

Comment: What would be the use case for fetching these programatically, especially when they have conveniently exposed these over environment configurations?https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-endpoints.html#production-ready-endpoints-exposing-endpoints

Comment: Use case is connected to security issues. I apply special rules to actuator endpoints and I want to do it automatically.

Comment: Spring provides this too. https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-endpoints.html#production-ready-endpoints-security. You should be able to set up an antmatcher for all `/actuator/*` endpoints

Comment: I will take a closer look at this. Maybe there is no simple replacement for my problem, maybe there is new approach in 2.x

Comment: There are a lot of new juicy introductions in actuator 2.x... a thorough read of the docs is pretty exciting actually...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Everything you need is in the `org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.PathMappedEndpoints` bean. This should set you on the right path, if you'll pardon the pun:

```
@Slf4j
@Component
public class ActuatorLogger {

  public ActuatorLogger(@Autowired PathMappedEndpoints pme) {
    log.info("Actuator base path: {}", pme.getBasePath());
    pme.getAllPaths().forEach(p -> log.info("Path: {}", p));
  }
}
```

`org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.security.servlet.EndpointRequest` is available to help you set spring security rules for actuator endpoints when you need to do it from code. For example, in your `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` implementation, this fragment could be merged in to your existing rules:

```
http.authorizeRequests()
      .requestMatchers(EndpointRequest.to(ShutdownEndpoint.class))
      .hasAnyAuthority("ROLE_ADMIN", "ROLE_SUPPORT")
```

Answer (score 3):

```
@Autowired
private HealthEndpoint healthEndpoint;

public Health getAlive() {
    return healthEndpoint.health();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Spring Boot Actuator 2.x exposes `/actuator` endpoints as configurable environment variables.

**Enabling Acutator Endpoints**

You can enable these [actuator endpoints](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-endpoints.html#production-ready-endpoints-exposing-endpoints) in your application.properties

```
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=info, health
```

or (with extreme caution) enable them all. Keep in mind that many of these are sensitive in nature.

```
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*
```

**Securing Actuator Endpoints** [(reference)](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-endpoints.html#production-ready-endpoints-security)

The documentation specifies this as a strategy to secure all endpoints. The `EndpointRequest` itself would be the closest alternative to what you were looking for (`MvcEndpoints`)

```
@Configuration
public class ActuatorSecurity extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.requestMatcher(EndpointRequest.toAnyEndpoint()).authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest().hasRole("ENDPOINT_ADMIN")
            .and()
            .httpBasic();
    }

}
```

You may also set up a particular antmatcher in case you have a different strategy or role that you would like to assign just to these endpoints

```
httpRequest.authorizeRequests().antMatcher("/actuator/*").hasRole("ENDPOINT_ADMIN")
```

Comment: This appears to not answer the question; Please link to comment (below the question) you base your answer on.